# c# crystal reports printtoprinter delay on windows server 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, windows-server-2012

Prints reports quickly on windows 7 prof to same networked printer.  From windows server 2012, up to 5 minute delay before it prints.

Same issue here but was never answered:
[Why is the Crystal Reports PrintToPrinter method so slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149463/why-is-the-crystal-reports-printtoprinter-method-so-slow/23135666#23135666)

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Latest printer drivers.

> Edit
>
> > It turned out to be the printer drivers installed on the server were older than the ones on the windows 7 machine. Once I installed the latest drivers on windows server 2012 the delay was completely gone

Comment: Can you please be more specific on how your problem got resolved?

Comment: Sure.  It turned out to be the printer drivers installed on the server were older than the ones on the windows 7 machine.  Once I installed the latest drivers on windows server 2012 the delay was completely gone.